# Counting r-digit, base q sequences with even number of 1s

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

Given:
Base = q, Length of sequence = r

To count the number of r-digit base q sequences with an even number of 1s.

I have given it a try and come up with the following solution:

`(A)` Since, $(q-2)^n$ of them contain sequences with symbols except 0 and 1, they can be counted as sequences containing an even number of 1s.

`(B)` Out of the remaining $(q^n - (q-2)^n)$ sequences, groups can be formed according to the patterns of the symbols (except 0 and 1, e.g., patterns of 2s, 3s, 4s,... ) in the sequences.

Since half of the sequences in each of the groups (formed in `step (B)`) have an even number of 1s. Hence, the general formula should be

$(q-2)^n + (q^n - (q-2)^n)/2$.

Am I going wrong somewhere?

If yes, kindly elucidate.

If no, what are the other efficient ways to arrive at a solution?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Why is that you are taking out the $0'$s?